# Specialized template dispatch independent of template parameter position

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, c++17

I have come across the problem of needing a template function that will have the same output so long as it's template parameters are the same, independent of position. Given that there are always two parameters.

I have a function:

```
template<typename Lhs, typename Rhs>
int func();
```

I would like `func<int, float>()` and `func<float, int>()` to call the same code.

I thought about a macro, which I like to avoid, but I need to not duplicate code when the two types are the same. So a macro such as:

```
#define DEF_TEMPL_IMPL(lhs, rhs, ret) \
template<>\
auto func<lhs, rhs>(){ return ret; }\
template<>\
auto func<rhs, lhs>(){ return func<lhs, rhs>(); }
```

will fail to compile because `DEF_TEMPL_IMPL(float, float, 3)` would cause a redefinition of `func<>`

I think SFINAE is the answer here, but can't quite think of a solution.

I will continue to ponder this, but some of the great minds of stack overflow might have a much better or more elegant solution than I can come up with before this question is answered.

So how can this be achieved?

Comment: You could just have a single specialization and have some kind of dispatcher which does some ordering canonicalisation. That depends on what types you are planning on working with and how many, though.

Comment: @TartanLlama I'm working with only fundamental types and there should always only be 2 template parameters.

Comment: Or actually, you could just make the primary template call forward with the template arguments switched.

Comment: @TartanLlama I already have that wrapped in a macro above

Comment: That's not quite what I mean, I'll write up an answer.

Comment: Why you need 2 template parameters? Also why not do it with tag dispatch and eliminate all template parameters?

Comment: @Nick it's for a jit compiler, this function tells you what the resulting type would be in a mathematical statement such as `Lhs(1) + Rhs(1)`. If you can think of a better way with tag dispatch then by all means submit another answer; it could be better than what I have already accepted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could just write one specialization for each type pair, then make your primary template delegate to `func<Rhs,Lhs>()` if it gets called:

```
//This will get called if no specializations match
template<typename Lhs, typename Rhs>
int func() {
    //Check if there is a specialization for the flipped pair
    return func<Rhs, Lhs>();   
}

//This will get called for <int,float> and <float,int>
template <>
int func<int,float>() {
    return 42;   
}

//Ditto for <bool,float> and <float,bool>
template <>
int func<bool,float>() {
    return 0xbeef;   
}

//Specializations with the same arguments are also supported by this scheme
template <>
int func<bool,bool>() {
    return 12;   
}
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e00a735f011b26602)

Comment: This won't *quite* work if you call `func<int,int>()`.

Comment: @n.m. you mean if you call with template arguments which have no specializations?

Comment: "template arguments which have no specializations" yes, exactly.

Comment: If you want to handle that gracefully, you could introduce a tag which says whether or not the primary template has already attempted a switch or not. Makes things a bit messier though. For the simple `<int,int>` case, you could just have a `static_assert` in the primary template which errors out if the arguments are the same.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another possible solution

```
template<typename A, typename B>
struct List { };

template<typename A, typename B>
struct Set { 
   Set(List<A, B>) { }
   Set(List<B, A>) { }
};

template<typename A>
struct Set<A, A> { 
   Set(List<A, A>) { }
};
```

Now, write each as an overload for `Set<A, B>`, like this

```
template<typename Lhs, typename Rhs>
int func() {
    return func(List<Lhs, Rhs>());
}

int func(Set<int, float>) {
    return 42;   
}

int func(Set<bool, float>) {
    return 0xbeef;   
}

int func(Set<bool, bool>) {
    return 12;   
}
```

This way, you can also define `func(List<float, int>)`, if for some reason, the order for `float, int` is important. If you accidentally defined both `Set<int,float>` and `Set<float, int>`, then the call would be ambiguous.

You can also have it validate at the time of definition of the overloads that you don't have duplicate `Set<A, B>` vs `Set<B, A>` defined by changing the definition of the binary `Set` to this

```
template<typename A, typename B>
struct Set { 
   Set(List<A, B>) { }
   Set(List<B, A>) { }

   friend void dupeCheck(List<A, B>) { }
   friend void dupeCheck(List<B, A>) { }
};
```

This however is not strictly necessary for this trick. Especially since the types in your JIT compiler may be easily manually ordered in a consistent way.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the order of types (i.e. `int` - 1, `float` - 2, `char` - 3).
Then implement a function that will sort these two types:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct Order;

// There should be a better solution for getting type id in compile time
// This will let you specify the order
template<>
struct Order<int>
{
    enum { Value = 1 };
};

template<>
struct Order<float>
{
    enum { Value = 2 };
};

template<>
struct Order<char>
{
    enum { Value = 3 };
};

template<typename A, typename B, bool swap>
struct Sort;

template<typename A, typename B>
struct Sort<A, B, false>
{
    typedef A First;
    typedef B Second;
};

template<typename A, typename B>
struct Sort<A, B, true>
{
    typedef B First;
    typedef A Second;
};


template<typename Lhs, typename Rhs>
int func_sorted()
{
    return 1;
}

template<>
int func_sorted<int, float>()
{
    return 2;
}

template<>
int func_sorted<float, int>()
{
    return 3;
}


template<typename Lhs, typename Rhs>
int func()
{
    typedef typename Sort<
        Lhs,
        Rhs,
        ((int)Order<Lhs>::Value > (int)Order<Rhs>::Value)>::First First;
    typedef typename Sort<
        Lhs,
        Rhs,
        ((int)Order<Lhs>::Value > (int)Order<Rhs>::Value)>::Second Second;
    return func_sorted<First, Second>();
}
```

so following code

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << func<int, float>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << func<float, int>() << std::endl;
}
```

will print:

> 2
>  2